# How can a Bazel aspect get source file list from java_library target?

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

Is there a way for an aspect to get a [JavaSourceInfoProvider](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/ca2977c2504df02ca2c8f8b6b2db75c6dad759ef/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/java/JavaSourceInfoProvider.java) from a java_library target? A source jar works for our compiler, but to generate source debugging information we need the actual source file's location, not a transient copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that that provider has been made available to Starlark, so you'll have to file a feature request to make it available.

However, it might be enough to just look at the `srcs` attribute of the rule directly with `ctx.rule.attr.srcs`.